# Is there any way to join two update queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-update

I have multiple update queries. I want to do them in one statement. The queries are

```
update user set name = 'Something' where id = '1';
update user set name = 'Newthing' where id = '2';
```

I want something like

```
update user set name = 'Something' where id = '1' && update user set name = 'Newthing' where id = '2';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use a `CASE` statement:

```
update user 
set name = 
    case when id = '1' then 'Something' 
         when id = '2' then 'Newthing' 
    end
where id in ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to sgeddes solution:

```
update user u 
join ( select 1 as id,'Something' as name 
       union 
       select 2, 'Newthing') as t 
    on u.id = t.id 
        set u.name = t.name;
```

Note that this will only work for mysql. Other DBMS such as Oracle, DB2, MSQL etc implement MERGE which is a standard construction:

```
merge into user u
using (
    values (1,'Something')
         , (2,'Newthing')
) t (id, name)
    on t.id = u.id
when matched then
    update set u.name = t.name
```

By adding another clause you can also insert

```
when not matched then
    insert (id, name) values (t.id, t.name)
```

Furthermore merge can also delete rows

Comment: A number of those other RDBMSs _also_ allow joins-on-update (version dependent, DB2 by platform too).  That merge is doing something else - it's inserting rows if they don't exist!

Comment: I should have mentioned insert the same way I did with delete, fixed that.